# Prove that the equivalence class $\mathbb R^3/V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let, $V$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $V=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R^3}|a=b\}$. Show that $\mathbb R^3/V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

I can understand that two 3 tuples $(a,b,c)$ and $(x,y,z)$ are related ie belong to the same equivalence class if $(a-x,b-y,c-z)\in V$ ie. if $a-x=b-y$.

What should I do after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $V=span\{(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ now we know that
$$
\dim\frac{\mathbb{R}^3}{V}=3-\dim V=1
$$

so, if $v$ it's a generator of the quocient, the map $v\mapsto 1$ extends to a linear isomorphism between $\frac{\mathbb{R}^3}{V}$ and $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

$V=\{(a,a,c)|a,c\in\Bbb R\}=\rm{span}\{(1,1,0),(0,0,1)\}\cong\Bbb R^2$.  And $\Bbb R^3/\Bbb R^2\cong\Bbb R$.